# Onclick function not working on input elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to 'listen' to clicks on any input field using the snippet below

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').onclick = function(){
    console.log('clicked an input field');
}
```

But nothing happens when I click on the input fields.

I double checked to make sure that input fields are being detected with **getElementsByTagName** using this snippet and it shows 200 objects

```
    elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.dir(elems);
```

Screenshot from console:

[image]

Is there a reason why this would not work? I tried moving code to different sections to make sure that document is loaded when it runs.

Plain javascript, not using jquery

Comment: are you sure you don't want onchange instead?

Comment: Did you make sure that the script is not executed until the page has been loaded? Are the elements already in the DOM tree when the script is executed?

Comment: @chriss i believe so because i put it inside window.onload and it's run right below the elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); which returns 200 elements, so I think they're there

Comment: @EugenSunic yep, I want to change the background color regardless of the field's value

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, you know you're getting a collection, but I suppose you also know, that you can't click on that ..?

Comment: @Teemu no i wasn't aware of that, i'll try attaching the onclick listener onto individual elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) returns a html collection.So you need to retrieve individual element and then attach event to it.

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('input')].forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked an input field');
  })
})
```

The three dots `...` is spread syntax to convert the collection to array so that array methods like `forEach` can be used

Alternatively you can use normal `for loop` to attach event to the element

```js
let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  })
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='1'>
<input type='text' id='2'>
<input type='text' id='3'>
```

Comment: thank you, strange i'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...''

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 on a mac

Comment: @RobertSinclair please see updated answer with alternative approach